# When is the 'javascript:' prefix valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I know that you can use a javascript: pseudo protocol for URLs in an `<a>` tag.  However, I've noticed that Firefox and IE will both allow '`javascript:`' to precede javascript code within a `<script>` tag.  Is this valid syntax?  Does it change the scoping rules?

Examples:
I've seen this many times:

```
<a onclick="javascript:alert('hello world!');">Hello World!</a>
```

But is this legal/valid syntax and does it do anything special:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
javascript:alert('hello world!');
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to know this as well, plenty of people use/abuse it.  Would be nice to know if its proper use or bad abuse.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with examples? I didn't understand the "I've noticed that firefox and IE will both allow 'javascript:' to precede javascript code within a tag." part.

Comment: he means <a href='javascript:alert("js code in here");'> alert </a>, you can really do all sorts of crazy stuff with that, like open windows and document.write to them.

Comment: Thanks, Allen, but isn't your example a case of the "pseudo protocol for URLs in an tag" thing that Heath mentioned first? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: oh wow yeah i'm dumb, i mis read the question, it appears alot of us did

Comment: Back to Heath then. Can you please give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Allen: the question originally did not have the <a> and <script> tags escaped, so they ended up being stripped from the post entirely. A small thing, but obviously confusing!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Outside of the `href` attribute (where it is a protocol specifier), *name*: just creates [a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/Label) (such as one might use with a `continue` or `break`).

#### See: [Do you ever need to specify javascript: in an onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick)

Answer (score 12):

You need the `javascript:` "protocol" when you want to put JavaScript in the `href` attribute of a link.

```
<!-- does not work -->
<a href="alert('some text');">link</a>

<!-- does work -->
<a href="javascript:alert('some text');">link</a>

<!-- also works -->
<a href="#" onclick="alert('some text');">link</a>
```

As far as I know (and please, if I'm wrong, someone correct me) there is no difference in scope, but there is a very important difference about `this`.

```
<!-- does not work -->
<a href="alert(this.href);">link</a>

<!-- alerts "undefined" -->
<a href="javascript:alert(this.href);">link</a>

<!-- works as expected, alerts "<url>#" -->
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this.href);">link</a>
```

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="alert('some text');">link</a> is considered best practice. conceptually, the url bar should be for urls, not scriptlets. javascript: will change the url bar, onclick will not. Good answer though, +1

Comment: Agreed. Though for some cases, using href="#" will cause your page to jump around. When that happens, I'm OK with href="javascript:;" or href="javascript:void();".

Answer (score 9):

One thing to consider, our testers would always ding us if we did something like

```
<a href='javascript:openwindowmethod("url");'> stuff </a>
```

Rather than

```
<a href='url' onclick='return openwindowmethod(this.href);'> stuff </a>
```

The first method would only work if you click on it but not if you shift or alt clicked on it, or right clicked and went to open in a new window.

The second method would support all of that, as well as the ability to function the way it intended if the user just plain clicked the link.

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript:` syntax can be used anywhere in a URL and executes the following string as a script. It is [part of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#javascript-protocol) and AFAIK is supported by all current major browsers.