# How do I trigger an HTML button when the “Enter” key is pressed in a textbox?

Tags: html, jquery, button, input, textbox

So the code that I have so far is:

```
<fieldset id="LinkList">
    <input type="text" id="addLinks" name="addLinks" value="http://">
    <input type="button" id="linkadd" name="linkadd" value="add">
</fieldset>
```

It is not in a `<form>` and is just as it is within a `<div>`.  However when I type something into the `textbox` called "addLinks" I want the user to be able to press Enter and trigger the "linkadd" `button` which will then run a JavaScript function.
How can I do this?
Thanks

**Edit:**
I did find this code, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
$("#addLinks").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#linkadd").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: bind to `keypress` and check for `e.charCode==13` (enter button).

Comment: Have you added jquery library reference before using above code?

Comment: Yes I did have the library referenced, not sure why it wasnt working, but its fine now.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, as @BradChristie mentioned, `keypress` or `keydown` mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/895231/544059) are the way to go.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#TextBoxId').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      $('#linkadd').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: adding 'return false' after the click event is helpful too, to avoid a default enter press on other buttons on the page

Comment: [dmitry_romanov's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24245592/8384) is better because it is pure html.

Comment: @McKay, no it is not. Buttons can be used for things besides forms. In fact, the OP's question is explicitly not in a form.

Comment: It is not currently in a form, but the OP doesn't state that it can't be in a form?

Comment: Just to add this works great but the brackets around the action in the if statement seem to be missing.

Comment: @deebs if you add return false after it will stop your key presses from appearing in the input, I.E you can't type.

Comment: @TimatMastersAllen I believe the 'return false' should be within the "if(e.keyCode==13)" block after the click event, meaning it only applies to enter press.  That would still fire the click, then return false so that it's not submitting the form or some other action that 'enter' may cause

Comment: @deebs quite right, not sure what I did on the day but I must have been having a brain fart.

Comment: **WARNING** [It is deprecated currently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45650898/4510033).

Comment: In this case, `==` produces unnecessary type-casting. Use `===` instead for optimization.

Comment: I found I had to use deebs' suggestion above, adding a line for 'return false;' after the click event or my text was wiped from the input field.

Comment: @deebs adding return false after click trigger will not let you type anything in textbox

Comment: Can also use `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 109):

## It is, <sup>yeah,</sup> 2021. And I believe this still holds true.

---

### DO NOT USE `keypress`

1. `keypress` event is **not triggered** when the user presses **a key that does not produce any character**, such as <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Escape</kbd>, left & right <kbd>Shift</kbd>, function keys(<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>).

> #### `keypress` event <sub>[*Mozilla Developer Network*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)</sub>
>
> The `keypress` event is fired when a key **is pressed down**, and that key normally **produces a character value**. Use `input` instead.

2. It has been deprecated.

> #### `keypress` event <sub>[***UI Events** (W3C working draft published on November 8, 2018.)*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-uievents-20181108/#event-type-keypress)</sub>
>
> - **NOTE** | The [`keypress`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-uievents-20181108/#keypress) event is traditionally associated with **detecting a [character value](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-uievents-20181108/#character-value) rather than a physical key**, and might not be available on all keys in some configurations.
> - **WARNING** | The [`keypress`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#keypress) event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but **this specification [deprecates](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-uievents-20181108/#deprecates) the use of this event type.** When in editing contexts, authors can subscribe to the [`beforeinput`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#beforeinput) event instead.

---

### DO NOT USE `KeyboardEvent.keyCode`

1. It has been deprecated.

> #### `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` <sub>[*Mozilla Developer Network*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)</sub>
>
> **Deprecated** | This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see [the compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Browser_compatibility) at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

---

### What should I use then? (The good practice)

```
// Make sure this code gets executed after the DOM is loaded.
document.querySelector("#addLinks").addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    if(event.key !== "Enter") return; // Use `.key` instead.
    document.querySelector("#linkadd").click(); // Things you want to do.
    event.preventDefault(); // No need to `return false;`.
});
```

Comment: how about: 
`if (event.key == "Enter") {
         document.querySelector("#linkadd").click();
     }`   ?

Comment: Note that `.key` isn't supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key – about 10% of people use browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @Anupam Good, _if you feel you don’t have to prevent the default event handler of the web browser_, which, in this case (`keyup`), likely doesn’t exist.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Well, worry not about that. Those who don’t know what `.key` is are super minor (under 3%) now.

Comment: So  there still isn't a nice way to do this with HTML.  Back in VB6 days there were two properties on buttons:  "Cancel" and "Default" If the button had Cancel=True, then hitting escape fired the button.  If "Default" was true, enter or return triggered the button. I suppose I could JS that up using a class or two. Hope W3C read this :(

Answer (score 100):

There are a js-free solution.

Set `type=submit` to the button you'd like to be default and `type=button` to other buttons. Now in the form below you can hit Enter in any input fields, and the `Render` button will work (despite the fact it is the second button in the form).

Example:

```
    <button id='close_renderer_button' class='btn btn-success'
            title='Перейти к редактированию программы'
            type=button>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'> </span> Edit program
    </button>
    <button id='render_button' class='btn btn-primary'
            title='Построить фрактал'
            type=submit
            formaction='javascript:alert("Bingo!");'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'> </span> Render
    </button>
```

Tested in FF24 and Chrome 35 (`formaction` is html5 feature, but `type` is not).

Comment: only works if you are within a form, the OP isn't using a form

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I missed that. Now I can see it clearly, thank you.

Comment: @Andrew, true, but it is trivial in most cases to wrap it in an do-nothing form...

Comment: Additionally this solution works on iOS virtual keyboard [Go] button whose default action is to submit.

Comment: Only works in a form _with an action specified_.

Comment: If you wrap it in a form with no action, it will not work in Firefox since submitting triggers a page reload. I was able to solve that problem by using the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13118834/12440938 (`action="javascript:void(0);"`)

Comment: I prefer this method because it avoids any javascript. However like the comments say, you must wrap it in a form.

Comment: @gabriel `formaction` will override action and prevent reloading

Comment: I know this is stupid, but please add quotes around the `type` value: `type='submit'`

Comment: it doesn't work on chrome 95

Answer (score 14):

1. Replace the `button` with a `submit`
2. Be [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), make sure you have a server side version
3. Bind your JavaScript to the `submit` handler of the form, not the `click` handler of the button

Pressing enter in the field will trigger form submission, and the submit handler will fire.

Answer (score 8):

You could add an event handler to your input like so:

```
document.getElementById('addLinks').onkeypress=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        document.getElementById('linkadd').click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works when input type="button" is replaced with input type="submit" for the default button which needs to be triggered.

Answer (score 4):

### **Just use `tabindex` and `autofocus` HTML Attributes**

**(Do not use Javascript for this solution!!)**

Newer *evergreen* browsers and older browsers **automatically** submit the first form submit button they find in the web page when the **ENTER**/**RETURN** key is pressed by a user. NO JAVASCRIPT NEEDED! Browsers have worked this way for nearly 20 years but new web developers have not bothered to learn about it.

If you have multiple submit buttons in a web page and want to control which submit button is pressed, its easy to do without JavaScript. Just set the `tabindex` to draw focus to the first form field set of controls that contains a submit button! Pressing the ENTER/RETURN keys will **trigger submission of form data when any form field control in the web page that is associated with a `submit` type `button` for that `form` has focus by the user.

To help with this focus, use the `autofocus` attribute set on any form field `input` in the `form`. The submit button for that form holding the input will then trigger when the ENTER/RETURN key is pressed. Otherwise, as mentioned above, pressing ENTER or RETURN on the keyboard automatically triggers the first available submit button for the page.

### How to Combine `tabindex` with `autofocus`

Instead of *JavaScripting* focus, an **easier solution** is to just add `tabindex=0` on any of your form fields or submit buttons inside a form element first, then `autofocus` on the first input control or submit button in your form and page. `tabindex` controls the order of which form fields and buttons get *focus* first. It is built into all browsers, old and new.

`Tabindex=0` assigns equal focus to every input and button in the page's list of indexed tab order page items. This makes sure a new tab order form field list is reordered and explicitly focused on first. `autofocus` shifts focus to your chosen form field. Because the focus is now on this `tabindex` grouping inside one of your `forms`, pressing enter triggers the first submit button in that grouping to respond to the ENTER/RETURN key command.

The user can now press "ENTER" on their keyboard to submit the form at any point they like. This also has the advantage that the first form field is focused on and ready for data by the user.

Additional: You can enter `tabindex=-1` on any buttons in the page to disable them from being in a tab index set or having tab focus. This also prevents them from being selected.

Lastly, never have *orphaned* input controls without a `form` HTML wrapper, like you have shown. Its not just broken HTML, but *semantically* wrong. **HTML was designed to hold multiple HtML form tags.** Because you can have multiple forms in a web page, you use `<form>` tags to control which form button goes with which form, or the "form" attribute set to the parent form holding it, as well as control user focus. Because you are using JavaScript to capture all form submissions, it does not matter what `type` (attribute) of buttons you use, or how you handle the scripts. All that matters is which ones will have FOCUS FIRST in the list.

FYI: `<button>` HTML elements always default to `"submit"` types if you do not add a type. Submit type buttons submit to the server, but JavaScript can easily shut that process down and stop submission. So it does not matter, except for the fact only submission types reliably respond to the ENTER event. You can use `type=button` for the type, which is just a non-submitting button. But I would stick with `type=submit` or no type which is the same (default) to avoid having `type=button` ones fail in some browsers.

An example below:

```
<form id="buttonform2" name="buttonform2" action="#" method="get" role="form">
  <label for="username1">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username1" name="username" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" title="Username" tabindex="0" autofocus="autofocus" />
  <label for="password1">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password1" name="password" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" title="Password" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-label="Password" />
  <button type="submit" id="button2" name="button2" type="submit" value="submit" form="buttonform2" title="Submit" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Stop using JavaScript for *simple solutions* HTML can solve. **HTML attributes used in web browsers have had this native ability for over 20 years.** New web developers should know this.

Comment: What if we don't want the url to change i.e. this isn't a form submission

Comment: Im guessing you mean you do not want the form to add a query string to the url when the submit button is triggered on ENTER? Simply set the method attribute on the form element as this: method="post"

Comment: Nice! It's so good to see some 20-year-old browser behaviour that is still relevant today :-)
Just for clarification, if you have a button within your form that you _don't_ want to be triggered when ENTER/RETURN is pressed within a control, make it `<button type='button' ... />` not just `<button ... />`. The submit button for the form should be `<button type='submit' ... />` or `<submit />`

Comment: That solution is fine except for the fact you cant submit multiple forms inside your page. So you just disabled them. If you are just using JavaScript for every form button submission then use the tabindex solution I mentioned and turn ALL BUTTONS to type=button. But that does not discount the value in maximizing your website for wider support in 20+ years of browsers :)

Comment: @thepiercingarrow If you dont need to submit your form fields to the server, just capture the submit using JavaScript. Nothing is submitted by the form in HTML in that case. If you are submitting the form traditionally using HTML and dont want the URL to change when you post using submit, simply use the attribute action="" or action="#" in the form HTML element to post to the same page. HTML is only designed to submit input fields. JavaScript is designed to disable that process. Mangling your HTML by hiding buttons or forms wont help.

Comment: Most competent and most appreciated post! This should receive more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, I am using jQuery you can write plain javascript.

Replace `sendMessage()` with your functionality.

```
$('#addLinks').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        sendMessage();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all add jquery library file [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and call it in your html head.

and then Use jquery based code...

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on some previous answers, I came up with this:

```
<form>
  <button id='but' type='submit'>do not click me</button>
  <input type='text' placeholder='press enter'>
</form>

$('#but').click(function(e) {
  alert('button press');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Take a look at the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmzuh1ws/1/)

EDIT:
If you dont want to add additional html elements, you can do this with JS only:

```
    $("input").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $("button").click();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure HTML [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

```html
<form class="my-form" action="javascript:myFunction();">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

By default, browsers will interpret <kbd>Enter</kbd> as submitting a form. [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) by default is type "submit" and accesses whatever is located in the form's `action` attribute (overridden if button's `formaction` is present). In this case for simplicity I use a javascript function with the [`javascript:` pseudo-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561550/when-is-the-javascript-prefix-valid-syntax), but it could be javascript event listener or a GET/POST method as in normal forms.

Answer (score 0):

I found w3schools.com howto, their try me page is at the following.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_trigger_button_enter

This worked in my regular browser but did not work in my php app which uses the built in php browser.

After toying a bit I came up with the following pure JavaScript alternative that works for my situation and should work in every other situation:

```
    function checkForEnterKey(){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
        }
    }

    function buttonClickEvent()
    {
        alert('The button has been clicked!');
    }
```

HTML
Press the enter key inside the textbox to activate the button.

```
    <br />
    <input id="myInput" onkeyup="checkForEnterKey(this.value)">
    <br />
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="buttonClickEvent()">Button</button>
```

Comment: It didn't work as I tried, you need to pass `event` in the `checkForEnterKey` function and the function should have event parameter too as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/155265/3943968

Answer (score 0):

This is the bare bones of what you need. A form `id` and change the button `type` attribute to `submit`. Add the `method` attribute to prevent a URL change or page reload.

```
<form id='form1' method='dialog'>
    <input form="form1" type="text" />
    <button form="form1" type="submit"> </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use jquery, but it should click your button on release of the enter key when focus is on the input box.

```js
function consoleLog() {
  // Clicking the button itself will work as well.
  console.log("enter key pressed")
}

document.getElementById("my_textbox").addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      document.getElementById("my_button").click()
    }
  });
```

```html
<input id="my_textbox" type="text">
<button id="my_button" onclick="consoleLog()">Submit</button>
```

If you want the enter key to perform an action from anywhere on the page you can try the following instead.

```
window.addEventListener(
  "keyup",
  (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      document.getElementById("my_button").click()
    }
  }
);
```

The following MDN link documents the `KeyboardEvent.key` function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="text" id="input_id" />    

$('#input_id').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
         // Call your function here or add code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I am using a kendo button. This worked for me.

```
<div class="form-group" id="indexform">
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <b>Search By Customer Name/ Customer Number:</b>
                @Html.TextBox("txtSearchString", null, new { style = "width:400px" , autofocus = "autofocus" })
                @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("btnSearch")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
                    .Content("Search")
                    .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var validator = $("#indexform").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),
          status = $(".status");
$("#indexform").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#btnSearch").click();
    }
});
</script>
```