# Defining a default button when pushing enter key

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a Grails app which contains a `.gsp` page with a number of `textField`s, several `submitToRemote` buttons, and a couple `actionSubmit` buttons on it. When filling out the `textField`s, I want to be able to hit enter after I'm done, and have it do the same as clicking a specific `submitToRemote` button.  Currently it is acting as if I clicked a specific `actionSubmit` button that I never intentionally specified.

I found this: [How to trigger HTML button when you press Enter in textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955222/how-to-trigger-html-button-when-you-press-enter-in-textbox) .  It seems like what I want, so I adapted it to my page, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

I'll forgo posting the entire `.gsp` but add what I feel is appropriate for the question.

Here is the button that is being activated currently:

```
<br>
    <g:hiddenField name="type" value="head"/>
    <g:actionSubmit value="Get Reports" action="showReports"/>
<br>
```

Here is the button that I **want** to be activated:

```
<g:submitToRemote value="find" url="[action: 'findCustomer']"
update="results" />
```

So what I did was add an id to both the target `submitToRemote` button, and 1 `textField`, then added the `<g:javascript>` tag wrapping around the scrip from the above linked page.  Which looks like this:

```
<g:textField name="lastName" id="inputTextBox"/>
```

...

```
<g:submitToRemote value="find" id="findCustomer" url="[action: 'findCustomer']"
update="results" />
```

...

```
<g:javascript>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#inputTextBox').keypress(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode==13)
     $('#findCustomer').click();
  });
});
</g:javascript>
```

Also, I am using the jQuery library as such:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

I'm not sure if my approach here is flawed, as I do need it to work on any of the 10 `textField`s on the page.  I went through the grails documentation and couldn't find anything that really matched this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution was quite close to what I had.

First I had to add an id to my `submitToRemote` button:

```
<g:submitToRemote value="find" url="[action: 'findCustomer']" update="results" id="submitForm"/>
```

Then in my `main.gsp` I added the proper script:

```
$(document).bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $("#submitForm").click();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The really important thing here is the `return false;` because without it, it will click the button, and then submit the form which is not what I needed.