# HTML/PHP change the button used when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

so i have 2 buttons

```
<button type="submit" name="print">print</button>
<button type="submit" name="search">search</button>
```

beside the button search there is a textbox

```
<input type="text" name="txtSearch" autofocus>
```

now what i want to do is whenever I press enter i'd like to submit using the button search. but what happens is the button print is always getting submitted because it is on top of button search. I cant put button search on top of print because of the design. Is it possible to do it in php? or do I need javascript? i'm just starting to program and trying to learn more. thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. Look for javascript form `onsubmit` event

Comment: Plus, your code suggest your have a form, or a form only require one submit, so the first one will be counted as the only one and other are ignore, so you might require JavaScript for one of the two, or for both depending on the action behind these buttons.

Comment: @zera: you can have as many submits as you want, and only the clicked one gets submitted. but OP isn't clicking EITHER button, hence the problem.

Comment: thank you i'll try to look it up! thanks for the idea!

Comment: @MarcB yup. i wasn't clicking thats the problem. because most of the time "enter/return" in the keyboard is used so i would want enter to use the search button instead of print button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger HTML button when you press Enter in textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955222/how-to-trigger-html-button-when-you-press-enter-in-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with php , you should use javascript or jquery .

add an id for your search input like this :

```
<button id='search' type="submit" name="search">search</button>
```

then you can use this code in jquery :

```
$('#search').keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
    $('#your-form').submit(); 
    }
    });
```

Comment: Search should be the default behaviour. Therefore print should use JavaScript. Also, `function(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can...

Separate into two forms:

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="print">print</button>
</form>
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="search">search</button>
  <input type="text" name="txtSearch" autofocus>
</form>
```

Or change the print button to:

- `<a href="print.php?id=123">Print</a>` or
- `<button type="button">print</button>`

Or you could put your search button first, and use `float` or some kind of `position:absolute` and `margin-top` CSS.

Or use JavaScript, as Parsa suggests.