# How to execute function when enter?

Tags: javascript

How do i execute function "myanswer1()", when the user presses enter inside the text field?
here is my code:

```js
function myanswer1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var y = x*x;
  document.getElementById("answersq").innerHTML = y;
  }
```

```html
<div class="holder" align="center" id="sq">
  <h1 align="center" class="write"><u>Square Finder</u></h1>
  <p align="center">
<input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter a number here">
<button onclick="myanswer1()" class="button1">Try it</button><p class="ans" id="answersq"></p>
```

The function should be executed only when the user is clicking enter inside the text field.

Comment: Check the linked answer: [How to trigger HTML button when you press Enter in textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45650898/2191976)

Comment: The dupe is mostly jQuery. The question was not tagged jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use the submit event, then no need to test

I added a few extras. It is recommended to use eventListener over an inline event handler

```js
const fld = document.getElementById("myText")
const answer = document.getElementById("answersq");

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const x = fld.value;
  answer.innerHTML = x * x;
  fld.select(); // focus and select the field content
})
fld.select(); // focus and select the field content
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="holder" align="center" id="sq">
    <h1 align="center" class="write"><u>Square Finder</u></h1>
    <p align="center">
      <input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter a number here">
      <button class="button1">Try it</button>
    </p>
    <p class="ans" id="answersq"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to detect the `keypress` event (whenever any key is pressed), and then check if the pressed key is the enter key (which has the number 13 assigned). <del>Check [Phong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65733567/9071943) to see how this is done in vanilla JavaScript (without jQuery).</del>

```js
$("#myText").on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        myanswer1();
    }
});

function myanswer1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var y = x*x;
  document.getElementById("answersq").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="holder" align="center" id="sq">
  <h1 align="center" class="write"><u>Square Finder</u></h1>
  <p align="center">
<input id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter a number here">
<button onclick="myanswer1()" class="button1">Try it</button><p class="ans" id="answersq"></p>
```