# Inline javascript, what is the 'javascript' in 'javascript:alert('asdf')'

Tags: javascript

I don't write inline javascript, but I see and work with it all the time in code bases that I work with:

`<div onClick='javascript:alert("asdf");'></div>`

I did some tests and found that in all my browsers, even IE in IE5 mode, you can change `javascript` to literally anything, and the `alert` will fire just fine.

`<div onClick='qwerty:alert("asdf");'></div>`

What is that delimiter? What is the history behind it? Is it ever needed or useful? I seem to remember that `<script type="text/javascript">` doesn't really need the `type` attribute set, is that related to this, as well? I tried some googling around, but it's hard to search for.

Comment: I believe this answers half your question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/62118

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) that is ONLY needed in IE if the first script on the page is VBScript
If you add `<script type="VBScript"></script>` to (older?) IEs your later scripts will fail if they are javascript specific and do not have the label javascript: to tell IE to switch back

See my answer here: [What does the JavaScript pseudo protocol actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068781/what-does-the-javascript-pseudo-protocol-actually-do)

Comment: so i can put any word i want and it 'll work on any browser??

Comment: Yes. It is treated as a label

Comment: But while you *can* put any word there, doing so it nonsense (unless you are going to break or continue from a loop), so don't put anything there.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's simply a label, analogous to:

```
label:
  statement;
```

Which is why `qwerty:alert("asdf")` works because it is legal Javascript.

IE does handle this differently; you can find more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/372279/263004).

Related answers and links:

- [When is the 'javascript:' prefix valid syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561550/when-is-the-javascript-prefix-valid-syntax)
- [The useless javascript: pseudo-protocol](http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html)

Comment: I believe I actually answer where it came from