# How can I use s:property in JavaScript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

In my struts2 Application I have a JavaScript function to do the cancel. this method is in the header and only do a window.location to my return URL. Since we did a migration from version 2.0.11 of struts 2.3.8 release, it no longer works. When I look at the generated HTML code we see that fails to interpret the tag s:property because the URL is empty. I do not see what does not work.

**in my IDE :**

```
function cancel() {
        if (!isModified || (isModified && askConfirmCancel())) {
            window.location.replace('<s:property value="#urlBack"/>');
        }
    }
```

**result with Firebug :**

```
function cancel() {
        if (!isModified || (isModified && askConfirmCancel())) {
            window.location.replace('');
        }
    }
```

**in JSP file :**

```
<tr>
    <td height="6%"align="center">
      <s:submit cssClass="button" key="common.initDelegate.label" align="center" theme="simple"/>
      <s:url id="urlBack" action="myAction" includeParams="none" escapeAmp="false">
        <s:param name="period.periodId" value="%{period.periodId}"></s:param>
      </s:url>
      <input type="button" onclick="javascript:cancel()" value="<s:text name="common.button.cancel"/>"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: You can also use a parametrized `url` tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

`<s:property value="#urlBack"/>` -- do we need "#" before `urlBack`. All we need is `urlBack` property in action class with `public String getUrlBack()` method. And the variable should get initialized before Action returns the success/result.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a variable `urlBack` then use it for render URL. For example

```
 <s:url var="urlBack" action="myAction" escapeAmp="false">
   <s:param name="period.periodId" value="%{period.periodId}"></s:param>
 </s:url>
 <input type="button" onclick="cancel();" value="<s:text name="common.button.cancel"/>"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function cancel() {
     if (!isModified || (isModified && askConfirmCancel())) {
        window.location.replace('<s:property value="#urlBack"/>');
     }
   }
 </script>
```

also

- `includeParams` by default is `none` since Struts 2.1.3.
- `id` attribute is replaced by `var`
- `javascript:` is a protocol for URLs not for JS functions, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561550/when-is-the-javascript-prefix-valid-syntax).