# Using onChange event and sending two objects as parameter gets me undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I made a simple function that depending on the text of the item selected from a dropdownlist, a textbox will change its maxlength property.

```
function cambiarLength(drop, textbox) {
    var option = document.getElementById(drop);
    var texto = option.options[option.selectedIndex].text;
    var field = document.getElementById(textbox);
    if (texto == 'RUC') {
        field.maxLength = 3;
    }
    else {
        field.maxLength = 6;
    }
};
```

Codebehind:

```
TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript: cambiarLength(this, txtDoc);");
```

Error:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'txtDoc' is undefined
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxSPM.jpg)

Comment: where is txtDoc defined?

Comment: txtDoc is the id that I use for that textbox.

Comment: You should use: `this.id`. Example: `TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript: cambiarLength(this, this.id);");`

Comment: The first this works, but when I do var option = document.getElementById(drop); option doesn't get drop instead it just null.

Comment: try in quotes. `document.getElementById("drop");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `txtDoc` is the literal id of the field, then it needs to be treated as a string. You should also remove the `javascript:` prefix as that will disallow `this` to be recognized in your routine.

```
TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "cambiarLength(this, 'txtDoc');");
```

See here regarding the use of the `javascript:` prefix:
[When is the 'javascript:' prefix valid syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561550/when-is-the-javascript-prefix-valid-syntax)

**UPDATE**

If you're using WebForms then you will want to use the `ClientID`, for example, if `txtDoc` is literally your code-behind control, you should do:

```
TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "cambiarLength(this, '" + txtDoc.ClientID +"');");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have tried a few things.
TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "cambiarLength(this.id, 'TxtDoc');");

var option = document.getElementById(ddl); this now does return the correct value.
var field = document.getElementById(txtbox); this is returning null/undefined.
For some reason I can't get the client.id from that textbox id 'txtDoc'.

Comment: @Popplar see my update, if you're using WebForms, your rendered txtDoc Id may end up looking something like this `ct100_MainContent_txtDoc`, etc, in which case you'd want to use the `.ClientID` prop.

Comment: I wanted to ask this, if possible, when passing "this" it is passing the object who called the function, is there a way to pass the object txtDoc instead of passing the clientID?

Comment: `this` will refer to the object from with the method was invoked. in this case; the only way you'd be able to pass txtDoc as a DOMElement would be to be to do this (which i don't advise) `cambiarLength(this, document.getElementbyId('" + txtDoc.ClientID +"'));`

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot for the help!