# remove appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

```
   $(function() {
           if(map_flag == 0)
              $("#buttons").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Import" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="javascript:import_q();" />');

       });

function upload_1()
{
  $("#buttons").val('');
   $("#buttons").html('')
}
```

In upload_1 function  how to remove the html that is appended in $("#buttons")
      i tried $("#buttons").val('');
       $("#buttons").html('');

It didnt work

Comment: Your `.html('')` version should work. Are you certain the `upload_1()` is getting called? Have you tried placing a simple `.alert()` inside that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
              $("#buttons").append('&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Import" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="javascript:import_q();" />');

       });

function upload_1()
{
   $("#buttons").html('')
}
</script>
<div id="buttons"></div>
<a href="#"  onclick="javascript:upload_1();" >Clear</a>
```

Works fine for me... How are you initializing the upload_1 function?

Comment: You do not need the "javascript:" inside an onclick on an anchor (<a>) tag.  This is messy, and considered bad practice.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick
 
http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol

Comment: I never use that. It was just a quick example of how it's working using his previous practice in the append(). I would use $().bind('click', ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buttons').html('');
```

will replace the `innerHTML` from the `#buttons` element.

```
$('#buttons').replaceWith('');
```

will replace the element `#buttons` itself and substitue it with `''` (nothing)

Sidenote: There is a typo in your code, a missing `;` behind `.html()`.