# What is "javascript:" in a JavaScript event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

What is `javascript:` in a JavaScript event handler?

Such as:

```
<input onkeydown="javascript:return false;" type="text" name="textfield" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you ever need to specify 'javascript:' in an onclick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a mistake. The pseudo-protocol is not needed in event handlers.

On a URL (`a` element `href` attribute, for instance), if you enter `javascript:` and follow that with javascript, the browser will run the javascript code.

For event handler, this is not needed, though the browser will not report an error.

Comment: @user635409 - I don't understand what you are asking in your comment.

Comment: It only doesn't throw an error by coincidence: it's valid syntax because it represents a label in JS.

Answer (score 8):

In this case it will be interpreted as [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). You could also write `foobar:` here, it would have the same effect.

It is not really needed in JavaScript code (I have never seen it used in real code), though it could be useful:

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a `break` or `continue` statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the `break` or `continue` statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

In your case, the markup should just be:

```
<input onkeydown="return false;" type="text" name="textfield" />
```

---

But if you use it as scheme in an URI, it tells the browser to interpret and execute the URI as JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(1);">Foo</a>
```

*(I'm not saying you should do something like this.)*

I assume people less familiar with JavaScript see this and think they have to put `javascript:` everywhere in front of JavaScript code in HTML, also in event handlers.

Comment: +1 for the label statement. There seems to be some long-standing confusion about this and I believe it stems from the use of MS's vbscript alongside JavaScript on the page. Although, even then it still doesn't do what you might expect (event handlers use the first defined language on the page).

Comment: @Andy: I've always assumed the confusion came from the widespread use of `<a href="javascript:doStuff()">`, but I have no evidence to back that up. Was/is it possible to write VBScript in an event handler attribute?

Comment: @Tim: I don't have any evidence either, but I remember seeing a piece of code that utilized features of VBScript not available to J[ava]Script, and that used `javascript:` and `vbscript:` in events. I don't think it works though, IIRC IE just picks a default to use in event attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write `return false`. At that time the `javascript` protocol was useful in links. `href` attribute: `<a href="javascript:return false">`

Answer (score 0):

It's something that shouldn't be there.

The `javascript:` prefix is primarily used for links, as the `javascript:` protocol in a browser would generally execute the code, for example:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('test')">Test</a>
```

In an event handler, though, it's already parsing JavaScript, thus it is not required. It's basically doing nothing.

Answer (score -1):

It's just markup to tell the browser that what follows is JavaScript code. However, it is not needed, so you don't have to include it.

Comment: That is not true. It will be interpreted as label and does not tell the browser anything.