# What is better - javascript:functionName() or just functionName()?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you ever need to specify javascript: in an onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick)

What is better to write in MVC3 when on the onclick event for example we call function with `functionName()`? `javascript:functionName()` or just `functionName()`?

Comment: Your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick

Please use search :)

Comment: Thanks, I used the search but after 10 minutes of searching javascript: and other similar things I gave up and wrote the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the best is to not mix javascript and markup. So you could attach this onclick event handler unobtrusively using javascript in a separate file. But as far as your question is concerned, you don't need the `javascript:` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

`javascript:` means different things depending on where it appears.

In a URI, it means to execute the JavaScript to get the resource. This is not [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) or [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and should be avoided.

In JavaScript (which the value of an `onclick` attribute is), it is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

- There is no point in labelling anything except `while`, `do`, `for` and `switch`.
- Most of the time, if a label would be useful, refactoring the code would be better.
- *javascript* is a terrible label for a statement in a JavaScript program.
- If you have a  `while`, `do`, `for` or `switch` in an onclick attribute, then you need to break it out into a function for the sake of your own sanity when you come back to read it later.
- onclick attributes are not [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to not use javascript in your HTML, for separation of concerns and unobtrusive javascript.

If you want to add an onclick event, use the following:

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = functionName
```

In your javascript file. This way, the presentation layer (HTML) is separated from the logic layer (Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Separating javascript from markup (aka [behavioral separation](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation) or [unobtrusive javascript](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript)) is the way to go. When you put your javascript within the markup (as in `<div onclick="[javascript:]startMyFunction()" ...>`), the expression has to be `eval`-ed, which spawns another interpreter.
So it's more efficient to put the scripting where it belongs: within the javascript tag.