# How to call javascript from a href?

Tags: javascript, html

How to call javascript from a href?

like:

```
<a href="<script type='text/javascript'>script code</script>/">Call JavaScript</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick

Comment: Unless there is a compelling reason, it's probably better to use <input type="button" /> for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`<a onClick="yourFunction(); return false;" href="fallback.html">One Way</a>`

** **Edit** **
From the flurry of comments, I'm sharing the resources given/found.

Previous SO Q and A's:

- [Do you ever need to specify 'javascript:' in an onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick) (and the IE related A's following)
- [javascript function in href vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348403/4202224)

Interesting reads:

- http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728201414/http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/the-useless-javascript-pseudo-protocol.html))
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Is the `javascript:` prefix in the onclick needed...?

Comment: @Dawson - you don't need `javascript:` in the onclick property.

Comment: Sure...if you're absolutely positive JavaScript is available. I don't like to rely on client-side. I don't like to rely on people knowing how to do anything in a UI (plan for the lowest common denominator -- even if it's intelligence of your visitors).

Comment: @Dawson If there is no Js, the onclick attribute does exactly _nothing_. There's really no need for the `javascript:` prefix.

Comment: @PhonicUK -- maybe this is some old school carry over for me. When did that disappear? Or was it ever truly a requirement? Is it a cross-browser compatibility thing? I throw "javascript:" onto it without even thinking...My point is -- I didn't start that habit because I thought it was "a good idea"

Comment: @Dawson, I don't think it was ever a requirement - just tolerated if seen.

Comment: @Dawson and say that if you forget to return false, the link (fallback.html) will be called...

Comment: @PhonicUK - "tolerated if seen"? LOL. No friggin way. It was part of the spec at some point -- had to be.

Comment: @Dawson, The HTML 4.01 Transitional spec (the oldest still widely used) doesn't specify it, neither does anything newer : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onclick

Comment: @PhonicUK -- I'll get back to you on this. I've been putting it in JS solutions like the Q since 1997(?). I'm guessing it was needed for Netscape or IE back then. I was just learning the stuff, so I didn't question those things. Now it's a deeply ingrained habit.

Comment: @Dawson: The `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute and the `javascript:` in the `href` attribute are two completely different things. In `href`, i.e. the "URL", it's a pseudo-protocol to tell the browser to interpret the string as JavaScript. In `onclick` it is a label (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which are syntactically valid, but utterly useless in this case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick though.

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks. On my way into the shop today, I was thinking about how "javascript:" was probably the same type of psuedo as "mailto:". Still haven't had time to research the history.

Comment: @FelixKling -- from that link you sent: "possible in IE to set the default language set to VBScript" << that's why we did it back then. Ironically, 99% of my career has been developing on a Mac. I have coded in a .NET environment, but I can't remember if we could call functions from the codebehind file or from the javascript. Don't have the means test such a theory now. Very interesting.

Answer (score 25):

```
<a href="javascript:call_func();">...</a>
```

where the function then has to return false so that the browser doesn't go to another page.

But I'd recommend to use jQuery (with `$(...).click(function () {}))`)

Comment: One link. One page. Tack on a JS Library? We all had jobs before JQuery. We'll all have jobs when JQuery has been forgotten.

Comment: @Dawson Before jQuery I hadn't coded anything ;-) ... But it doesn't seem to me as if JQ would be as fast forgotten... In ten years perhaps? Perhaps when there exist better alternatives...

Comment: I understand. But that's kind of the point. This question doesn't require a library. And it could have been asked and answered the same way 10 years ago.

Comment: @Dawson Then you could also ask: what if the specification wouldn't support JS anymore, but something else? A library could there maybe replace the legacy JS code by parsing it and transforming it and then eval. — And the library code will work, once you have a working version on your server.

Comment: I'm not trying to be the devil's advocate here. The question is tagged [javascript] and [html]. JQuery is not synonymous with JavaScript. That's the biggest reason I was "arguing" against using a library. I realize in the world of web dev today, JQuery or the like is probably being used.

Comment: @Dawson This was just a notice, that this is better in my opinion. I don't say that you have to use it.

Comment: I don't think you have to return false with `href="javascript:call_func();"`  I think you just have to return false for `onclick="call_func()"`.  I think returning false in href=javascript confuses some browsers.

Comment: in firefox if I return false in javascript, I get `javascript:call_func();` in the url and "false" on the page.  If I don't return anything, it works as expected.

Comment: @bwoebi go to https://alex028502.github.io/return-from-href-javascript/ with firefox and click the 'test' button.  I am using firefox 51.0.1

Comment: @Alex028502 ah, firefox. [Works perfectly in Safari.] Well… then don't return false :-)

Answer (score 12):

The proper way to invoke javascript code when clicking a link would be to add an `onclick` handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">LinkText</a>
```

Although an even "more proper" way would be to get it out of the html all together and add the handler with another javascript when the dom is loaded.

Comment: This is bad practice.

should be `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myFunction">LinkText</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Using JQuery would be good;

```
<a href="#" id="youLink">Call JavaScript </a>



$("#yourLink").click(function(e){
//do what ever you want...
});
```

Comment: FYI - I'm guessing you're getting down votes because this question could have been posted in 1997. There was a solution then; however, JQuery wasn't around.

Comment: I'm not. I'm saying, this solution doesn't require a JS library. Your comment suggests the web would fall apart if JQ wasn't around.

Comment: You are assuming too much and i do not recommend there is no else solution for this. I just said it would be good.

Comment: I'm not. The question is even tagged "javascript" "html". I made NO assumption. I used the requirements of the question/tags to formulate my answer.

Comment: OK then. JQuery is one of Python libraries, not Javascript.

Comment: +1 for showing this crispy, elegant solution. It's the best answer, when already on the jQuery track (and who is not these days?)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript code is usually called from the `onclick` event of a link. For example, you could instead do:

**In Head Section of HTML Document**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myFunction(){
//...script code
}
</script>
```

**In Body of HTML Document**

```
<a href="#" id="mylink" onclick="myFunction(); return false">Call JavaScript </a>
```

Alternatively, you can also attach your function to the link using the links' ID, and HTML DOM or a framework like JQuery.

For example:

**In Head Section of HTML Document**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("mylink").onclick = function myFunction(){ ...script code};
</script>
```

**In Body of HTML Document**

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Call JavaScript </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid inline javascript altogether, and as I mentioned in my comment, I'd also probably use `<input type="button" />` for this. That being said...

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337937/how-to-call-javascript-from-a-href" id="mylink">Link.</a>
```

---

```
var clickHandler = function() {
     alert('Stuff happens now.');   
}


if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('mylink').addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
} else {
    document.getElementById('mylink').attachEvent('click', clickHandler);
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/pDp4T/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
 <a href="javascript:
  console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(HTMLDivElement))">
       1. Direct Action Without Following href Link
  </a>

<br><br>

  <a href="javascript:my_func('http://diasmath.blogg.org')">
      2. Indirect Action (Function Call) Without Following Normal href Link
  </a>

<br><br>

 <!-- Avec « return false » l'action par défaut de l'élément
 // <a></a> (ouverture de l'URL pointée par
 // « href="http://www.centerblog.net/gha" »)
 // ne s'exécute pas.
 -->
 <a target=_new href="http://www.centerblog.net/gha"
          onclick="my_func('http://diasmath.blogg.org');
 return false">
     3. Suivi par défaut du Lien Normal href Désactivé avec
     « return false »
  </a>

<br><br>

 <!-- Avec ou sans « return true » l'action par défaut de l'élément
 // s'exécute pas.
 -->
 <a target=_new href="http://gha.centerblog.net"
          onclick="my_func('http://diasmath.blogg.org');">
     4. Suivi par défaut du Lien Normal href Conservé avec ou sans
     « return true » qui est la valeur retournée par défaut.
  </a>

<br><br>

<!-- Le diese tout seul ne suit pas le lien href. -->
  <a href="#" onclick="my_func('http://diasmath.blogg.org')">
      5. Lien Dièse en Singleton (pas de suivi href)
  </a>

  <script language="JavaScript">
   function my_func(s) {
       console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Document));
       window.open(s)
   }
  </script>

<br>
<br>

 <!-- Avec GESTION D'ÉVÉNEMENT.
 // Événement (event) = click du lien
 // Event Listener = "click"
 // my_func2 = gestionnaire d'événement
 -->
  <script language="JavaScript">
   function my_func2(event) {
      console.dir(event);
      window.open(event.originalTarget["href"])
   }
  </script>
 <a target=_blank href="http://dmedit.centerblog.net"
     id="newel" onclick="return false">
     6. By specifying another eventlistener
     (and deactivating the default).
  </a>
  <script language="JavaScript">
      let a=document.getElementById("newel");
      a.addEventListener("click",my_func2)
  </script>
```

Comment: Each link is the illustration of a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this worked for me while nothing else did but just in case anyone else is still looking...

In between head tags:

```
<script>
     function myFunction() {
           script code
     }
</script>
```

Then for the < a > tag:

```
<a href='' onclick='myFunction()' > Call Function </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to process a function and not process the href it self, add the return false statement at the end of your function:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript: function() {... ; return false} return false">click</>
```

Comment: Three remarks: 1) `javascript:` is useless here and 2) you defined a function but never call it. 3) The way you define the function probably results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

another way is :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('testing')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit
This will create a link with Edit after clicking on editing a function name as **edit** will be called.

Comment: <a href="javascript:edit(\'' + key + '\',\'' + mvName + '\')">Edit</a>