# What is the use of 'javascript:methodName(); in an anchor link?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the use of 'javascript:methodName(); in an anchor link?

I have seen the following in some code. What is use of the "javascript:"?

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:getUserName()"/>Click</a>
```

It works if in both (with and without "javascript:") condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case `javascript:` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a `break` or `continue` statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the `break` or `continue` statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.

It is of no use in this case and instead of `javascript` you could use any other word there.

It is probably only (mistakenly!) used because one typically sees this in the `href` attribute (where `javascript:` is a pseudo-scheme):

```
href="javascript:getUserName()"
```

but it has a totally different meaning in `on*` attributes.

Related: [Do you ever need to specify 'javascript:' in an onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372159/218196)

Comment: Thanks for the effort and reply. Thank you.