# How to use input value in object [javascript]

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get User input(name) by onChange function by get element's value,
and want to print it by using jQuery .html

but in browser it keep show like:

> text [object HTMLInputElement]' text

```js
var getUserName=()=>{var userName= document.getElementById("userName").value }

var getname = {"something": {"character": "text" + userName + "text"},

$("#character").html(getName[something]["character"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="userName" onchange="javascript:getUserName()"/>
```

Comment: I helped you a little on the formatting here... But edit again to make it reproduce your issue. You have at least a missing `#character` element in the HTML and a typo on `getName`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the unbalanced quotes, and unbalanced braces, different spellings of variable names, referencing `something` as a variable instead of a string literal, ...etc, etc, you need to move the code that you want to execute upon the event, *all inside* that event handler.

Correction:

```js
var getUserName = () => {
    var userName= document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var getName = {"something": {"character": "text" + userName + "text"}};
    $("#character").html(getName["something"]["character"]);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="userName" onchange="getUserName()"/><button>Enter</button>
<div id="character"></div>
```

Some other remarks:

- Using jQuery just for this is overkill, as you can just assign to `.textContent`. But if you're going to use jQuery any way, then use it to the full (so no `document.getElementById` then...)
- Don't use `html()` when you are only planning to assign *text*, not HTML.
- Bind your event handler via code, not via HTML attribute, and at least drop the "javascript:" prefix, as that creates a label (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick)).

Answer (score -3):

put double quotation for something too may work

Comment: This should be a comment.